# error : invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix

1.This is a part of a program to add two matrices using pointers.

2.I am getting the error `error : invalid type argument of unary '*'  (have 'int')`.

3.Here `A` and `B` are initialized 2D arrays and `c1`, `r1` are no. of columns and rows respectively of matrix `A` and `c2`, `r2` are no. of columns and rows respectively of matrix `B`.

```
main() {
    int i, j, A[10][10], B[10][10], r1, r2, c1, c2;

    //Inputting Matrix A
    printf("\nFOR SET A ");
    printf("\n\nEnter number of rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &r1);
    printf("\n\nEnter Number of Columns :");
    scanf("%d", &c1);
    printf("\n\nEnter Elements of matrix A :\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
           scanf("%d", (*(A + i) + j));
       }
    }

    //Inputting Matrix A
    printf("\n\nFOR SET B:");
    printf("\n\nEnter number of rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &r2);
    printf("\n\nEnter Number of Columns :");
    scanf("%d", &c2);
    printf("\n\nEnter Elements of matrix B :\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r2; i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
           scanf(" %d", (*(B + i) + j));
       }
    }

     //Displaying matrix A
     printf("\n\nMatrix A is :\n\n");
     for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
              printf(" %d ", *(*(A + i) + j));
         }
         printf("\n\n");
     }

     //Displaying matrix B
     printf("\n\nMatrix B is :\n\n");
     for (i = 0; i < r2; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
              printf(" %d ", *(*(B + i) + j));
         }
         printf("\n\n");
     }

     //Calling the Addition function
     add(A, r1, c1, B, r2, c2);
 }

 void add(int **A, int r1, int c1, int **B, int r2, int c2) {
     if (r1 == r2 && c1 == c2) {
         int i, j;
         printf("\n\nThe Addition of matrix A and B is :\n\n");
         for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
             for (j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
                 printf(" %d ", ((*(*(A + i) + j)) + (*(*(B + i) + j))));
             }
             printf("\n\n");
         }
    } else
        printf("\n\nMatrices are not of same order !!!");
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself what the type of `*(A+i)` is. Array syntax is easier to read, use that instead.

Comment: look like you dereference so much that you tried to dereference an int why don't you use A[i][j] this is also count as dereferencing otherwise this look very confusing my suggestion but you can keep your style

Comment: i have my college assignment to do addition using pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how many elements you actually enter, your arrays are declared with a **fixed** size. Your function must know about this, it has **at least** to know the number of elements in one row, so it can calculate the offset to the next row correctly. In your case, use the following prototype:

```
void add(int (*A)[10], int r1, int c1, int (*B)[10], int r2, int c2)
```

Comment: @NiRajWagh just mentioning this wasn't obvious until you edited your question to show the declarations. See [chqrlie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45647884/2371524) for some important array-related knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not compute the offset of the elements correctly.

You can correct the code this way:

```
void add(int *A, int r1, int c1, int *B, int r2, int c2) { 
    if (r1 == r2 && c1 == c2) {
        int i, j;
        printf("\n\nThe Addition of matrix A and B is :\n\n");
        for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
                printf(" %d ", A[i * c1 + j] + B[i * c2 + j]);
                // if you must use the less readable pointer syntax
                // use this strictly equivalent form instead:
                //printf(" %d ", *(A + i * c1 + j) + *(B + i * c2 + j));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("Matrices are not of same order !!!\n\n");
    }
}
```

The function can be called this way:

```
int mat1[3][4] = { ... };
int mat2[3][4] = { ... };

add(&mat1[0][0], 3, 4, &mat2[0][0], 3, 4);
```

Note that since you only handle matrices with the exact same geometry, you could further simplify the main loop this way:

```
    int i, j, k = 0;
    printf("\n\nThe Addition of matrix A and B is :\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c1; j++, k++) {
            printf(" %d ", A[k] + B[k]);
            k++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
```

As Felix Palmen commented, C99 introduced variable length arrays and a syntax to pass them as function arguments:

```
void add(int r1, int c1, int (*A)[c1], int r2, int c2, int (*B)[c2]) { 
    if (r1 == r2 && c1 == c2) {
        int i, j;
        printf("\n\nThe Addition of matrix A and B is :\n\n");
        for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
                printf(" %d ", A[i][j] + B[i][j]);
                // if you must use the less readable pointer syntax
                // use this strictly equivalent form instead:
                //printf(" %d ", *(*(A + i) + j) + *(*(B + i) + j));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("Matrices are not of same order !!!\n\n");
    }
}
```

The function can be called this way:

```
int mat1[3][4] = { ... };
int mat2[3][4] = { ... };

add(3, 4, mat1, 3, 4, mat2);
```

Note however that this feature is not supported by some mainstream C compilers and was made optional in the latest version of the Standard (C11).

**EDIT:** Your case is actually very different: your matrices have a fixed size of 10x10 and you want to handle 2D submatrices. You function should look like this:

```
void add(int A[][10], int r1, int c1, int B[][10], int r2, int c2) { 
    if (r1 == r2 && c1 == c2) {
        int i, j;
        printf("\n\nThe Addition of matrix A and B is :\n\n");
        for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
                printf(" %d ", A[i][j] + B[i][j]);
                // if you must use the less readable pointer syntax
                // use this strictly equivalent form instead:
                //printf(" %d ", *(*(A + i) + j) + *(*(B + i) + j));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("Matrices are not of same order !!!\n\n");
    }
}
```

The function can be called this way:

```
add(mat1, 3, 4, mat2, 3, 4);
```

Finally, your prototype `void add(int **A, int r1, int c1, int **B, int r2, int c2)` is incorrect because `A` and `B` are arrays of arrays of `int`, not arrays of pointers to arrays of `int`.

Note also that the prototype for `add` should appear before the code that calls it.  The prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)`, your syntax is obsolete and no longer supported since C99.

Comment: While this works, isn't it *strictly speaking* UB for accessing the arrays `mat1[0]` and `mat2[0]` out of bounds?

Comment: i have to use pointers method as i have this as my college assignment

Comment: Alternative would be a signature like `add(size_t r1, size_t c1, int (*A)[c1], /* ... */)` if you're comfortable with VLAs...

Comment: @NiRajWagh `x[n]` and `*(x+n)` are two ways writing **the same thing**, always. So it doesn't matter.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: *isn't it strictly speaking UB*? That's an interesting question for a more advanced readership. It would take an extraordinarily vicious system to break this code.

Comment: Heads up: the edit to the OP *invalidates* this answer. OPs error is using an array with **fixed** dimensions, but not letting the function know about them.

Comment: @Felix yup bro, i have to write 2 codes, one using pointers and another without pointers.So i have to use *(x+n) in this code as x[n] is used in my other code.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I updated the answer with a VLA approach.  Both solutions work and `void add(int **A,int r1,int c1,int **B,int r2,int c2)` is definitely incorrect.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, I never suggested that. Some answers are of horribly bad quality :o

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Of course you did not, I copied the fragment from the OP's update.

Comment: @chqrlie - sorry - you were first - deleted :)

Comment: @chqrlie just a little remark: you could of course use the array notation with VLA arguments as well (like `A[][c1]`). I prefer to write it like the compiler sees it *after* adjusting the types, as in my answer. I think a discussion on that topic would be interesting, unfortunately it's off-topic on SO.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: As you noted, the arguments `r1` and `c1` and not the dimensions of the matrix, just the size of the submatrix to handle. You solution `void add(int (*A)[10], int r1, int c1, int (*B)[10], int r2, int c2)` or something equivalent like `void add(int A[10][10], int r1, int c1, int B[10][10], int r2, int c2)` is definitely the correct approach.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, I was just referring to writing a) array types in function declarations and let the compiler *adjust* them to pointer types or b) pointer types directly. You do a) for the "*correct*" solution with the fixed dimension (`int A[][10]`) and b) for the VLA solution (`int (*A)[c1]`). Nothing wrong with either, it's just mixing styles :)

Answer (score -2):

You have an array of arrays. This means you should use

```
void add(int **A,int r1,int c1,int **B,int r2,int c2)
```

as the function prototype.
Also can you show the entire the code?

edit: (full code)

```
int** mat_add(int** A, int **B, int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2){
int** C, i, j;
C =(int **)calloc(r1*c1, sizeof(int*));

for(i=0;i <r1;i++)
    C[i] = (int *)calloc(c1, sizeof(int));

for(i = 0;i < r1; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < c1; j++)
        C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
return C;
}
void print_arr(int** C, int r, int c){
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            printf("%d\t", C[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int **A, **B, r1, r2, c1, c2;
    int i;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d", &r1, &r2, &c1, &c2);
    A = (int**)calloc(r1*c1, sizeof(int*)); //used for allocating memory for pointers
    B = (int**)calloc(r2*c2, sizeof(int*));

    for(i=0;i <r1;i++)
        A[i] = (int *)calloc(c1, sizeof(int)); //used for allocating memory for each row of integers having size of length of column
    for(i=0;i <r2;i++)
        B[i] = (int *)calloc(c2, sizeof(int));

    //take matrices as input from the user here
    //...

    if(r1==r2 && c1==c2){
        int ** C = mat_add(A, B, r1, c1, r2, c2);
        print_arr(C, r1, c1);
    }
    else
        printf("MATRICES MUST BE OF SAME SIZE!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah sure. but the full code is not acceptable in the comment box. where should I post it

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and add the full code?

Comment: This answer is just wrong. Even in the original revision, the question said *2D-Arrays* were used, not arrays of pointers.

Comment: See my edit.
You can use this technique to achieve a 2D array.